# XML view for android photosphere?

Tags: android, xml, photosphere

I see google has an API for embedding Google Cardboard panaromas into an app with the VrPanoramaView, but i am looking for a xml view to correctly handle google's own PhotoSphere images from its Google Camera app. I do not want it to externally load the photosphere viewer but view in app as you would with an imageview. Is there a view to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VrPanoramaView does handle Googles photosphere. The options need to be set correctly though. For photosphere use:

```
imageView = (VrPanoramaView) v.findViewById(R.id.uploadPictureView);
VrPanoramaView.Options options = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
options.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
imageView.loadImageFromBitmap(image, options);
```